# What does the word "pager" mean in SQL Server Agent context?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I want to know the meaning of `pager` in SQL Server Agent context. Anybody can explain it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pager) is a simple beepy device from pre-mobile phone era: you can configure SQL Server Agent to page you, in addition to emailing you.

Nowadays, you'd send an SMS or such. The Wikipedia link above has info on modern usage "Pager use in the 21st century"

And thank you for making me feel old...

Comment: Oh I know this device. I'm not a native English speaker and don't know this thing is called a pager. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's the usual meaning: [Pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pager): for operator alerts

Answer (score 1):

Remember the pagers that people had in the 90s..you would call the pager, leave your number and the person would call you back...well SQL agent has that ability too...but I don't think anyone has a pager anymore

Answer (score 1):

> Pager
>   Includes the e-mail address for
>   the message between the prefix and the
>   suffix.

Taken from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180064.aspx)